# decrypt AES-128 encrypted .m3u8 playlist and .TS files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to decrypt a `.m3u8` playlist, I followed these steps :

- create a directory
- copy the key to a key file, ie `my.key`, and place it in the dir. Note
  that keys can be rotated, if the playlist has multiple keys copy all
  of them to different files.
- copy all `.ts` segments to the same dir
- copy and edit the `playlist.m3u8` and use just the filename(s) for the
  key(s) URI(s) and segments.

and using this command to decrypt the playlist

```
ffmpeg -i playlist.m3u8 -c copy output.ts
```

but I got this error : `Invalid data found when processing input`

here is my m3u8 :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="my.key"
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:6.000,
s-1-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:6.000,
s-2-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:6.000,
s-3-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:12.000,
s-4-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:12.000,
s-5-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:6.000,
s-6-v1-a1.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

- whats wrong with my command ?
- how to not convert playlist to one `.TS` file? I want to decrypt files separtly

Answer (score 10):

Try specifying the full local path in your manifest so make the KEY like:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="file://path/to/local/my.key"
```

and the TS chunks all like:

```
file://path/to/local/s-6-v1-a1.ts
```

If that doesn't work then ffmpeg could need the input for a m3u8 to be served over HTTP. So put your m3u8 file and the key and all your chunks on some web dir and rerun your ffmpeg command using the URL for the m3u8 so it'd be like:

```
ffmpeg -i http://mytestwebserver.com/playlist.m3u8 -c copy output.ts
```

If you don't have access to a webserver you can install some local and free like MAMP.  I have had no issues using the above command to copy a HLS stream locally when the input is a HLS URL.

Comment: This method worked for me. I end up downloading and substituting all the ts-chunks and the encryption key with their local paths using the following script https://gist.github.com/grwlf/e1876f5d78cb6e66791809771d7bf36b Note it is very playlist-dependant.

Comment: Does the ```key``` file have some specific format for data inside it? I got the decryption key but not from URI provided in M3U8 file, now I don't know how to use that key! Already tried to save a ```sample.key``` file and put the key inside it, didn't work.