# How do I scrape an embedded video using .ts and .m3u8 files

Tags: python, web-scraping, video

I want to scrape the videos from a site. They're all like the video on this page: https://ucha.se/watch/7721/orientirane-v-prirodata-liavo-diasno-gore-dolu-pred-zad. I've done this type of thing before but I just can't seem to do it with this site. If you go to the network tab in dev tools you can see a playlist.m3u8 file containing the names of chunklist_xxxxx.m3u8 files, which are the different distributions of the videos. Each chunklist_xxxxx.m3u8 file has the names of the .ts video segments and also a URI pointing to some place under the https://ucha.se domain. What do I do after I download all the videos? I tried using ffmpeg but it just returns a 403 Forbidden error

Comment: _"...Also a URI pointing to some place under the https://ucha.se domain"_ Your stream is AES encrypted. That "URI" is the decryption key's link. Does it look like `https://ucha.se/streaming/key/?s=`? It has the `/?s=` part? If not then try searching Network tab for text `key` in the **filters** box. After saving the file, you can rename it (_eg:_ maybe rename as `test.key`) and then edit the m3u8 playlist entry of `#EXT-X-KEY` to point to your folder path (it contains the TS files and the key file).

Comment: PS: See also [decrypt AES-128 encrypted .m3u8 playlist and .TS files with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47844205/2057709) for ideas about the process.